# Is there a container for function arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, containers, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Suppose I have a template for a variadic function:

```
template <typename... Types>
auto variadic(Types... arguments) /*...*/
```

Is there any C++ container (let's call it ArgList) that would allow the following piece of code to work?

```
ArgList args;
args.push_back(arg1);
args.push_back(arg2);
/*...*/
variadic(args);
```

If there is not, can such a container even be implemented?

Comment: A [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) seems relevant. `std::tuple` doesn't use push_back however.

Comment: In case it's not clear `std::tuple` is your container, and `std::apply` is how you call a function with it.

Comment: Isn't `std::tuple` a compile-time template?

Comment: Yes, there was nothing in your question that made me think you wanted anything else. After all `variadic` is also a compile time template.

Comment: Are you asking if this can be done for a specific variadic function template (that you can edit), or if there is a general solution for all such templates (similar to the `arguments` object in JavaScript)? (If it's your own function, then why not write it so that it takes a container as a parameter?)

Comment: templates are a compile-time concept. If you want to make them runtime, you have to create a wrapper function with switch case that instantiates and calls all respective variants. Then you would need an upper bound for the number of arguments and a finite list of possible parameter types. Or you include a C++ compiler engine in your runtime. Then you would get total flexibility.